# How to extract only domain country from URL (Data Studio / regex)

Tags: regex, looker-studio

I'm struggling with extracting from URL only country for example `.pl` from `https://www.google.pl`.

At this moment I'm able to extract `google.pl` from provided url using the following code:

```
TRIM(REGEXP_EXTRACT(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(URL, "https?://", ""), R"^(w{3}\.)?", ""), "([^/?]+)"))
```

What is needed to change in this code to provide only `.pl` instead of `example.pl`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, r'https?://[^/]*\.([^/]+)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FyjxLX/1). *Details*:

- `https?://` - `https://` or `http://`
- `[^/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `/`.

Comment: it works, thanks. Any suggestion what should I change if I want ".pl" instead of "pl"?

Comment: @kamil `REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, r'https?://[^/]*(\.[^/]+)')`